# typecasting in php

Tags: php, oop

I have an interface in PHP

```
interface IDummy{
public function DoSomething();
}
```

I have another class that implements this interface.

```
class Dummy implements IDummy{
public function DoSomething(){

}
```

How can I type cast the Dummy Object to IDummy in PHP, so that I can call it as

```
$dum = new Dummy();
$instance = (IDummy)$dum;
$instance->DoSomething();
```

Can I do this in PHP?

Thanks and Regards
Abishek R Srikaanth

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cast is completely unnecessary. It will simply work.

And the Dummy objects will be considered an instance of IDummy if you ever check it with one of the various type hinting functions.

This works... no casting needed:

```
interface I { 
  public function foo(); 
};

class A implements I {
  public function foo() { }
}

function test(I $obj) {
  $obj->foo();
}

$a = new A();
test($a);
```

Comment: could you please provide an example. I always get an error when I try the above syntax....

Comment: Don't do `$instance = (IDummy)$dum;`. Fix your code, try it again, and if it still fails, update your post with the code snippet that isn't working.

Comment: PHP doesn't require the verbosity that, say Java, does as your example suggests. You don't need the cast because PHP is already aware as to  which objects are implementers of the interface.

Comment: For sample implementation see my anwer.

Comment: The sad part is that even though function test is declared to take an argument of interface I, it doesn't prevent the function from accessing any other property or method of class A not included in interface I. So, if your intent was to restrict what the caller can do with your object to only what's included in the interface - sorry that won't work. The only way is to declare other members or functions private or protected.

Answer (score 3):

If class `Dummy` already implements `interface IDummy`, there's no need to cast `$dum` to `IDummy` - just call method `DoSomething()`.

```
interface IDummy
    {
    public function doSomething();
    }

class Dummy implements IDummy
    {
    public function doSomething()
        {
        echo 'exists!';
        return;
        }
    }

$dummy = new Dummy();
$dummy->doSomething(); // exists!
```

Comment: What I would like to do is the following:

I have another class 

class DoFinalImplemention{

public function Implement($dum){
 //This is where I want to do the type cast to Interface to call the DoSomething method. The parameter that I get is a IDummy object

$obj = (IDummy)$dum;
$dum->DoSomething();
}
}

Can I do this, or will your implementation work as well?

Thanks and Regards
Abishek R Srikaanth

Comment: You can call object of class implementing IDummy without casting it to that interface. Simply do call it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it could be fun, see java functionality regarding this issue.

```
interface I { 
  public function foo(); 
};

class A implements I {
  public function foo() { echo 'This should be accessible.'; }
  public function baz() { echo 'This should not be available.'; }
}

$dum = new A();
$instance = (I) $dum;
$instance->foo(); // this should work

$instance->baz() // should not work
```

Note: This code throws error. It seems that you can not cast interface like that. In java is possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the class name from the configuration or something else that you don't know, I think this should work:

```
$classname = 'Dummy';
$reflectionClass = new \ReflectionClass($classname);
$instance = $reflectionClass->newInstance();
// $dum = new $className; //you can do this as well I guess
if( $instance instanceof IDummy){
  $instance->DoSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code should simply be:

```
$class = new ClassName;
$class->yourMethod();
```

As @konforce pointed out, not typecasting is required. You might want to check PHP method_exists() function `http://php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php`.